# jQuery for radio button using radiio input name is not working

Tags: jquery

Hope all doing well!!

I need to show border around the div when i click on the radio button div but problem is that the name is show like this:- input[name="properties[DOOR OPTION] you can see DOOR OPTION  are handle a space. As i understand main problem is space thats why my jquery is not working.

I am not using class for this because all radio button are work differently and dynamically.

Please see

```
<input type="radio" class="rb_677900_299393" name="properties[DOOR OPTION]" value="Pre-Hung" data-option_value_key="1">
```

[Please check my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f15M5.png)

```
$(function() {
    $('.bold_option_value label span.bold_option_value_element input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
      if ($('input[name="properties[Size]"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('.bold_option_value_title').removeClass("intro");
         $(this).parent().siblings('.bold_option_value_title').addClass("intro");
      }
    });
    $('body').on('live','.bold_option_value_title',function(){
      if ($('input[name="properties[DOOR OPTION]"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('.bold_option_value_title').removeClass("intro");
         $(this).parent().siblings('.bold_option_value_title').addClass("intro");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: your code should work, can you share code snippet or jsfiddle with your issue recreated

Comment: okay, sure. I will send you the code, but problem is the code is working the shopify backend. I have added only the jquery on it

Comment: Can you please check input[name="properties[DOOR "blank space problem" OPTION]"]:checked and let me know then problem from door option

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ankushsharma26199_6/bj8znfw9/2/ Please check my code is not working properly

Comment: I tried your code and it is giving proper count of 1 for radio button checked when i tried with alert. I did not understand why you are using `live` when it is deprecated since version 1.9 jquery. I think i can help you if you explain me what exactly you want to achieve here

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. Is this what are looking for?

HTML

```
<div>
    <div>
        <b>RADIO 1 :</b>
        <div class="dv1"><label><input type="radio" name="properties[DOOR OPTION]"/>ABC</label></div>
        <div class="dv1"><label><input type="radio" name="properties[DOOR OPTION]"/>DEF</label></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>RADIO 2 :</b>
        <div class="dv1"><label><input type="radio" name="properties[WHATEVER]"/>GHI</label></div>
        <div class="dv1"><label><input type="radio" name="properties[WHATEVER]"/>JKL</label></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>RADIO 3 :</b>
        <div class="dv1"><label><input type="radio" name="properties[TEST SPACE]"/>MNO</label></div>
        <div class="dv1"><label><input type="radio" name="properties[TEST SPACE]"/>PQR</label></div>
        <div class="dv1"><label><input type="radio" name="properties[TEST SPACE]"/>STU</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("change",function(){
    var target = $(this).closest("div"); // Find the closest div with this input.

    target.addClass("active") // Add class active (border)
    .parent("div").find("div") // Find all the others div within parents div
    .not(target).removeClass("active"); // Remove others div with class active except the target
});
```

JSFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/synz/ajkz8u3o/

Comment: I need same like this

Comment: This was an example. From this example, you should know what to do next, with the rest of your code. And you're not giving all the rest of the information what already you have done. Like what's the rest of your html and css. So, I just make an example based on what I understand from your question, which is "I need to show border around the div when i click on the radio button". Plus radio name with space. If you check my JSFiddle example there. Is it supposed to do something like what you want or not?